# How to extract a particular inner-text value of an elements when there are many classname have similar names

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to extract the innertext value of an element whose attribute name is **same with 4 others elements in a webpage.**

Difference is I am trying to extract only the **innertext value of 3rd element (which begins with numericals For ex. 123123123)**. While other 3 elements have innertext values starting with non numeric values (EX GA1233412FGH).

Please let me know how can do this.

Below is my code snippet. Here attributename= jobid is the same with 3 other webelements.

```
    Set objSubCollec = objCollection(0).contentWindow.document.getElementById("tab")
    Set objElement = objSubCollec.contentWindow.document.getElementById("Frame_4")
    objElement.Focus
    Set objElement = objElement.contentWindow.document
    Set elm = objElement1.getElementsByTagName("span")
        i = 6
          For Each e1 In elm
              If e1.getAttribute("orafield") = "jobid" 'jobid is the common attribute name with 4 other elements
                 temp = e1.innerText
                 Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("C6") = temp
                 i = i + 1
                 'MsgBox temp
          End If
          Next
```

Comment: Once you capture the innertext, and the one you need always starts with a numeric value, capture the first character (you can use `Left` for this) and check if its a numeric value (you can use `IsNumeric` for this)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the innertext you want to extract always starts with numeric value, and the other elements don't, you can just add a simple condition:

```
If IsNumeric(Mid(el, 1, 1)) Then
```

Comment: It tried with below code. It's not going into the IF loop of the code. Any heads up .

        i = 6
                   For Each e1 In elm2
                      If e1.getAttribute("orafield") = "meterSerialNumber" Then
                      If temp = IsNumeric(Mid(e1.innerText, 1, 1)) Then
                         temp = e1.innerText
                        Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("C6") = temp
                         End If
                        i = i + 1
                      End If
            Next

Comment: It doesn't because your condition `If temp = IsNumeric(Mid(e1.innerText, 1, 1)) Then ` is wrong, use condition from my answer and it will work